# Build a bijection $F\colon B^{A_1} \to B^{A_2}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\varphi\colon A_1 \to A_2$  be a bijection between  sets $A_1$ and $A_2$. How to build a bijection $F\colon B^{A_1} \to B^{A_2}$ where $B$ is an arbitrary set?

It is  clear that the following map

$$
F(h)(x)=h(\varphi^{-1}(x)), \text{  for } h\colon A_1 \to B  \in B^{A_1}  \text{ and } x \in A_1,
$$
is a bijection.

**Question.**  How  to prove accurately  that $F$ is a bijection? It is necessary to prove separately that $F$ is injection and surjection or there is another more simply and direct way to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write down the inverse map, as follows: $G:B^{A_2}\rightarrow B^{A_1}$ by $G(g)=g\circ\varphi$. It is now easy to check that this map is actually an inverse. (Note that I omitted the $x$ and used composition instead, which makes it more convenient at least notationally.) If you change a bit of notation, your statement is a special case of the fact that a functor maps isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

Comment: ... but showing from first principles that $B^-$ is a (contravariant) functor looks to be at least as involved as just doing the problem directly.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: indeed. I was just pointing a more general statement, which might help the op to see the big picture.